# Xml Deserialization or malformed?

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have some XML from a 3rd party API that looks like this:

```
<root>
  <Data>
    <sub_id>3</sub_id>
    <email>something@something.test</email>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <sub_id>7</sub_id>
    <email>test@what.biz</email>
  </Data>
</root>
```

And I'd like to deserialize it to a class like this:

```
public class root
    {
        //[XmlArray("Datas")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Data", typeof(Data))]
        public Data[] Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int subscriber_id { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
```

But of course this doesn't work. 
The line I have commented out, 'Datas', that would fix it, if I insert a  element to wrap the array of 'Data' elements, but I can't. As I said, this XML is from a 3rd party(one that's a little lax on how XML works).

So is this doable with some different C# code/attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove class root and deserialize array itself (also Rename subscriber_id to sub_id in class Data). Here is the code

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data[]), new XmlRootAttribute("root"));
            Data[] datas;
            using (var tr = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                datas = (Data[])serializer.Deserialize(tr);
            }
```

However If deserialization is all you need and source xml format as simple as that then you can parse it using XLinq, it is more efficient (10 vs 20 sec for 1 million deserializations on my machine):

```
var xml =
@"<root>
  <Data>
    <sub_id>3</sub_id>
    <email>something@something.test</email>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <sub_id>7</sub_id>
    <email>test@what.biz</email>
  </Data>
</root>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (var dataElem in xdoc.Root.Elements("Data"))
{
    var subId = int.Parse(dataElem.Element("sub_id").Value);
    var email = dataElem.Element("email").Value;
}
```

Comment: nice work dude! I was sure this was possible because it looked like properly nested xml, but I didn't even think of that typeof(Data[]) thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The xml is not malformed. All you have to do is use `[XmlElement]` instead of `[XmlArray]`. Example:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public Data[] Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        [XmlElement("sub_id")]
        public int SubscriberId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

I have just tested the above with your sample and it loaded fine.